# Can we protect does 99999=1

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1) is currently locked. I believe that it would be best to protect it instead, as the purpose of protecting a question is to prevent users adding pointless answers to it. I believe that we should then start protecting any other questions where too many additional and pointless answers are added.

Comment: As long as we publicly condemn it.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/670/can-we-finally-kill-9991